# Using a module inside another module with the same name

Tags: ruby

I have a module like this

```
module A
  module ClassMethods
    def a
      "a"
    end
    def b
      a
    end
  end
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend ClassMethods
  end
end
```

I want to factor `b` into it's own module because `B`s are clearly not `A`s. The `b` method depends on `A`, and I would like the methods defined in `A` to be available to `B`.

Doing this:

```
module B
  module ClassMethods
    extend A
    def b
      a
    end
  end
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
end
```

It does not work. Nor does `include`. I tried moving `include` or `extend` as well as the how constants are references. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `extend A` action in the `included` callback of the module `B` instead of adding it in the `ClassMethod` definition, like the following code does:

```
module A
  module ClassMethods
    def a
      "a"
    end
  end
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend ClassMethods
  end
end

module B
  module ClassMethods
    def b
      a
    end
  end
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend(ClassMethods)
    klass.extend(A)
  end
end

class C 
  include B
end

C.b
# => "a"
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood what you wanted. I split up `module A` and `module B`. When I include those in a new class `Klass`, I have access to both method `a` and method `b`, whereas method `b` from `module B` depends on method `a` from `module A`:

```
module A
  module ClassMethods
    def a
      "a"
    end
  end

  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
end

module B
  module ClassMethods
    # include A::ClassMethods here and you can do only 'include B' inside Klass
    def b
      "Called from B: %s" % a
    end
  end

  def self.included(klass)
    klass.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
end

class Klass
  include A, B
end

p Klass.a # => "a"
p Klass.b # => "Called from B: a"
```

As I understand you can define the same Module in different places, no need to say `include`, `extend` or anything. As you see neither `Module A` nor `Module B` uses those keywords, they both just define `ClassMethods`.

Of course, you will have to include `module A` wherever you use method b of `module B` or else the method call to `a` will fail. You can also do `include A::ClassMethods` inside `B::ClassMethods`, that way you only need to `include B` inside `Klass`.

Comment: An upvote for you, but not quite what I was looking for. I suppose I should have been more clear. I wanted B to be able to be included on it's own, managing it's own dependency on A, but A should be able to be mixed into a context independantly of B. @Rafa's answer was a little closer to what I was looking for. But thank you for your help!

Comment: I see, however if you do `include A::ClassMethods` below the definition of `B::ClassMethods` you are still able to *only* `include B` in `Klass`, since `B` will include whatever was defined in `A::ClassMethods`. That is very close to what you describe as 'B managing it's own dependency'. I left that code commented out in my post. However, perhaps Rafa's `extend(A)` is better, frankly I don't really know what the exact differences are between the two approaches (`include` vs `extend`). Glad I could help somewhat anyway!